# Show that $xg_x(x, y) + yg_y(x, y) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Need help with this.

Suppose that $G(u, v)$ is a differentiable function of two variables and that $g(x, y) =
G(x/y , y/x)$. Show that $xg_x(x, y) + yg_y(x, y) = 0$.

Where $g_x(x,y)$ and $g_y(x,y)$ are the partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the chain rule $$\partial_x g(x,y) =  G_x(x/y,y/x)\partial_x (x/y) + G_y(x/y,y/x)\partial_x(y/x) $$
$$
= \frac{1}{y} G_x(x/y,y/x) - \frac{y}{x^2}G_y(x/y,y/x)$$
and similarly
$$
\partial_y g(x,y) = G_x(x/y,y/x)\partial_y(x/y) +  G_y(x/y,y/x)\partial_y(y/x)
$$
$$
= \frac{-x}{y^2}G_x(x/y,y/x) + \frac{1}{x}G_x(x/y,y/x).
$$
Multiply the first equation by $x$ and the second by $y$, then add them to get your result.